# Elastic search cluster socket hand up

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes where I have 1 master node and 2 data nodes, I am getting socket hang up error very frequently in my cluster. Is there any way to divide the requests in cluster?

```
Master node :-
RAM - 8GB
Cores - 4

First Data node :-
RAM - 20GB
Cores - 8

Second Data node :-
RAM - 8GB
Cores - 4
```

Can we divide the requests in EScluster like all read queries will go to "First Data node" and all write queries will go to "Second Data node", is it possible? will it be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't MongoDB and works differently: There is no splitting up of reads and writes like that. And with 3 nodes all of them need to be master eligible nodes otherwise you'd have a single point of failure. For the simple case of 3 nodes I'd get similar nodes and let them all be data and master-eligible nodes.